# How to find the next working hours and day from a given set of working hours?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, data-structures, ecmascript-6

I have an hours array that gives the working hours of a firm for each day of the week.
I need to display whether the firm is open at the current time or not.
If it is open currently, then I need to show the closing time also.

If it is closed currently, then I need to show the next earliest opening time.
If the firm is opening the next day, then I need to show "Opens 9:00am(say) tomorrow".
If it opens some other day, then that day should be shown instead of the keyword tomorrow.
If the firm is closed throughout the week, then I need to show "Temporarily closed."
My hours array is of the below format:

```
[
        {
            "day": 0,
            "startHour": "9:00",
            "endHour": "18:00",
            "isOpen": 0,
            "workingHours": [
                {
                    "startHour": "9:00",
                    "endHour": "18:00"
                }
            ]
        },
{
            "day": 1,
            "startHour": "9:00",
            "endHour": "18:00",
            "isOpen": 0,
            "workingHours": [
                {
                    "startHour": "9:00",
                    "endHour": "18:00"
                }
            ]
        },
....so on for all 7 weekdays
]
```

Here "day":0 means Monday, 1 means Tuesday, and so on.
I am able to write the logic for when the firm is open at the current time. I am facing difficulty while finding the next opening day, especially, when the next opening day is a previous day of the week than the current day.
This is how I am deciding if the firm is open currently:

```
const currentTime = new Date();
    const currentDay = currentTime.getDay();
    const currentHour = currentTime.getHours();
    const workingHours = hoursOfOperations.find(function (hours) {
        return hours.day === currentDay;
    });
    if (workingHours) {
        if (
            currentHour >= workingHours.startHour &&
            currentHour < workingHours.endHour
        ) {
            return {
                isOpen      : true,
                closingTime : `${workingHours.endHour}`
            };
        }
    }
```

For finding next opening day:

```
const nextOpeningDay = hoursOfOperations.find(function (hours) {
        return hours.day > currentDay && hours.isOpen === 1;
    });
```

I was thinking if I could run a circular loop exactly 7 times and then return the nearest opening day details. Can anyone help me here? I am also trying to use modulo operator here to find the day.

Comment: Several questions about your input data.  First, is that fixed, coming from an external source or is it something you can modify?  Because it has a weird redundancy: why do the `workingHours` nodes seem to repeat the values of their parent objects?  If both are required in the data, which do we use for calculation?  Also, what is the `isOpen` integer?  Does that say whether it's open *at the moment* or if it's open *at all on this day*?  Something else?  And what does its `0` value mean?

Answer (score 0):

With no answer to my comment on the question, I tried this with my own input structure.  It should be easy enough to convert to use your format; you would also need to supply a list of days of the week, which I embed in the input data.

I consistently return a string, something like one of these:

- "Temporarily closed."
- "Open. Closing at 18:00."
- "Closed. Opening at 08:00"
- "Closed. Opening tomorrow at 08:00."
- "Closed. Opening Monday at 08:00."
- "Closed. Opening next Saturday at 08:00."

Your code is returning an object with properties but you also request the "Temporarily closed" string.  I don't like to mix output types; I chose the strings.  But this could easily be altered to return an object with the properties we calculate.

So this is not an exact answer to your question, but it should help you move in the right direction:

```js
const report = (hours) => (date) => {
  const day = (date.getDay() + 6) % 7 // start with Monday
  const time = date.toString().slice(16, 24)
  if (!(hours[day].closed) && time < hours[day].open)  {
    return `Closed. Opening at ${hours[day].open}`
  }
  if (!(hours[day].closed) && hours[day].open <= time && time < hours[day].close) {
    return `Open. Closing at ${hours[day].close}.`
  }
  const offset = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] .find (
    offset => !(hours[(day + offset) % 7].closed)
  )
  if (!offset) {return `Temporarily closed.`}
  const hour = hours[(day + offset) % 7]
  return `Closed. Opening ${offset == 1 ? 'tomorrow' : (offset == 7 ? 'next ' : '') + hour.day} at ${hour.open}.`
}

const hours = [
  {day: 'Monday',    open: '08:00', close: '18:00'},
  {day: 'Tuesday',   open: '08:00', close: '18:00'},
  {day: 'Wednesday', open: '12:00', close: '22:00'},
  {day: 'Thursday',  open: '08:00', close: '18:00'},
  {day: 'Friday',    closed: true},
  {day: 'Saturday',  open: '08:00', close: '12:00'},
  {day: 'Sunday',    closed: true},
]

const checkStatus = report(hours)

const testCases = [
  new Date(2023, 6, 5, 23, 0, 0),  // 2023-07-06, 16:15 (Wednesday, after closing)
  new Date(2023, 6, 6, 16, 15, 0), // 2023-07-06, 16:15 (Thursday, during hours)
  new Date(2023, 6, 6, 19, 0, 0),  // 2023-07-06, 19:00 (Thursday, after closing)
  new Date(2023, 6, 8, 12, 30, 0), // 2023-07-08, 12:30 (Saturday, after closing)
  new Date(2023, 6, 8, 4, 0, 0),   // 2023-07-08, 04:00 (Saturday, before opening)
]

testCases .forEach(
  (t) => console.log(`${t.toString().slice(0, 21)}: "${checkStatus(t)}"`)
)
```

We first find the day of the week, doing a little shuffling to start with Monday. Then we pull a string representing the time from the input date, using the `toString()` output format rather than something like `toISOString()` so that we're simply ignoring timezone questions.  We could alternately specify the times in UTC, but that would likely be more confusing.

Then we do four checks.  First we see if we we're before opening time for today. Second, we see if we're between opening and closing for today.  If neither is true we find the first number of days from now, between `1` and `7`, where we have open hours.  If we don't find such a number, we report that we're temporarily closed.  If we do find one, then we report using that day, with some logic to handle "tommorow" versus "Tuesday", versus "next Tuesday".  (That last would only show up if we are open only Tuesdays, but it's after closing time.)

I don't handle "9 am"/ "4:30 pm", returning just things like "09:00", and "16:30".  That would be an easy tweak.

What would be harder, and would probably require a different algorithm, is if you had multiple open hours in a day, say a restaurant open 6am to 2pm and 4pm to 10pm.